# BYOD and software licenses

Tags: untagged

I am curious on what is the proper way to handle this scenario.

About half of the staff at my company (30+) bring their own laptops, this includes developers.

How does one normally handle software purchases that are needed for work but are to be installed on personal workstations?

The key concerns are

- Who covers the cost? I assume the company
- If bought with company finances, what do we do when the employee leaves? Enforce the leaving staff to uninstall all software owned by company?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is now leveraging the ability to have selective apps uninstalled/wiped remotely for your 2nd question.

Comment: And this question really only leads to opinion answers.  TomTom has a great answer, but it may not apply in your company.  This is something that goes beyond IT administration and delves into Legal, "C Level" involvement, HR, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Who covers the cost? I assume the company

Sure the company. COmpany wants it, company pays it.

> Enforce the leaving staff to uninstall all software owned by company?

Not needed. Have them sign a waiver when they get it that they understand they do not own the license and have to uninstall it when they leave. Keep all documentation on your side. When they leave try to make them sign that they deleted it - but mostly inform them the licenses are not theirs to use anymore. Attachment a list of licenses to please uninstall. If they do not uninstall, the crime is theirs, not yours.

Comment: Can't argue with this. Cover your back and then worry no more!

Comment: Especially because what does uninstall mean? Developers want the disc as copy anyway (repair etc.) and an uninstall means nothng when they have a backup.